# Function analytic on annulus bounded by $|z|^2$

Tags: complex-analysis

This problem comes from an old prelim

"Let $f$ be analytic on an open neighborhood of the annulus $1\le |z|\le 2$. Assume that $|f(z)|\le 1$ when $|z|=1$ and $|f(z)|\le 4$ whenever $z=2$. Show that $|f(z)|\le |z|^2$

Here's what I have so far: since $f$ is analytic on a neighborhood of the annulus, it is also analytic on the interior of the annulus. Therefore, the restriction $f_{A}$ cannot attain its $\sup$ or $\inf$ on the interior. So it must obtain its $\sup$ and $\inf$ on the boundary of the annulus. Also, $g(|z|)=|z|^2$ is monotone in $|z|$ so that $\sup_{z\in A}g(z)=4$ and $\inf_{z\in A}g(z)=1$ and these values are obtained on the boundary. So, IF I knew that $|f(z)|$ were monotone in $|z|$, then I think I see why the statement follows, but I can't quite figure out if this assumption is necessary or how to prove the result if it isn't necessary. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Use Schwartz Lemma

Comment: @mwomath That's for discs, not annuli.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $g(z)=\frac{f(z)}{z^2}$. Then $g$ is holomorphic on a neighborhood of the annulus $1\leq |z|\leq 2$, and $|g(z)|\leq 1$ on the boundary of the annulus. The maximum modulus principle then implies that $|g(z)|\leq 1$ on the whole annulus, i.e. $|f(z)|\leq |z|^2$.