# Concerning the maximum modulus principle.

Tags: complex-analysis

> If $f$ is continuous on $A=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:1\leq|z|\leq2\}$, analytic in $\operatorname{int}(A)$, $|f(z)|\leq1$ for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$ with $|z|=1$ and $|f(z)|=4$ for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$ with $|z|=2$, prove that $|f(z)|\leq|z|^2$ for all $z\in A$.

**The following is the attempted solution.**

Define $g(z)=f(z)/z^2$ for all $z$ in $A$. Then $g$ is analytic in $\operatorname{int}(A)$, as $z\neq0$ for all $z\in A$, and continuous in $\operatorname{int}(A)$. Obviously $\operatorname{int}(A)$ is a bounded domain. Therefore the maximum of $|g(z)|$ occurs on $\partial A$. But $\partial A=\partial D_1(0)\cup\partial D_2(0)$. Also we have $|g(z)|\leq1$ on $\partial D_1(0)$ and $|g(z)|=1$ on $\partial D_2(0)$. Therefore $|g(z)|\leq 1$ on $\partial D_1(0)\cup\partial D_2(0)=\partial A$, i.e. $|f(z)|\leq|z|^2$ for all $z\in\partial A$. Hence $|f(z)|\leq|z|^2$ for all $z \in A$.

Is the above reasoning correct?

Comment: Your reasoning is correct, see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1789648/function-analytic-on-annulus-bounded-by-z2.

Comment: For next time, note that you don't need to encase every single mathematics symbol in dollar signs. It's enough to encase each _expression_. Click the edit button right below your last line to see how I've done it.